# Scrollview + stacklayout bottom part of content blank after validation labels made visible

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

am developing an app that takes an input from user with error labels for input validation
the error label visibility default value is false.
am having more than a 10 entry and their error label.
[image]

and after the app takes input and validates it with error labels it hides everything from the middle of the screen to the very end of the layout.

[image]

this my xaml code

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout
            Margin="20">
            
            <!--Unit Type Picker-->
            <Grid>
                
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                                                                                                       
                <Label 
                        Grid.Column="0"                            
                        Text="{xct:Translate UnitType}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource PickerLabelStyle}"/>
                <Picker 
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding UnitTypeList,Mode=OneWay}" 
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding UnitTypeIndex,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                        Style="{StaticResource PickerStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding UnitTypeError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding UnitTypeErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />

            <!--Unit IsFurnished Picker-->
            <Grid>
                
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <Label 
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Text="{xct:Translate Furnished}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource PickerLabelStyle}"/>
                <Picker 
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding IsFurnishedList,Mode=OneWay}" 
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding FurnishedIndex,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                        Style="{StaticResource PickerStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding FurnishedError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding FurnishedErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />
            
            <!--Unit National ID-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate UnitNationalID}"
                Text="{Binding UnitNationalID}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding UnitNationalIDError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding UnitNationalIDErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />


            <!--Floor Num-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate FloorNum}"
                Text="{Binding FloorNum,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding FloorNumError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding FloorNumErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />
            

            <!--Unit Space-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate UnitSpace}"
                Text="{Binding UnitSpace,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding UnitSpaceError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding UnitSpaceErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />
            

            <!--Living Room Space-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{Binding LivingRoomSpacePH,Mode=OneWay}"
                Text="{Binding LivingRoomSpace,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>

            <!--Rooms Num-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{Binding RoomsNumPH,Mode=OneWay}"
                Text="{Binding RoomsNum,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>

            <!--Lights Num-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{Binding LightsNumPH,Mode=OneWay}"
                Text="{Binding LightsNum,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>
                        
            <!--Baths Num-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate BathsNum}"
                Text="{Binding BathsNum,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding BathsNumError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding BathsNumErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />
            

            <!--Maid Rooms Num-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate MaidRoomsNum}"
                Text="{Binding MaidRoomsNum,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding MaidRoomsNumError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding MaidRoomsNumErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />

            <!--Air Conditioner Type Picker-->
            <Grid>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label 
                        Grid.Column="0"                            
                        Text="{xct:Translate AirCondType}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource PickerLabelStyle}"/>
                <Picker 
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding  AirCondTypeList,Mode=OneWay}" 
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding AirCondTypeIndex,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                        Style="{StaticResource PickerStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding AirCondTypeError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding AirCondTypeErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />

            <!--Air Cond Power-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate AirCondPower}"
                Text="{Binding AirCondPower,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding AirCondPowerError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding AirCondPowerErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />
            

            <!--Rent-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate Rent}"
                Text="{Binding Rent,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding RentError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding RentErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />

            <!--Discount-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{Binding DiscountPH,Mode=OneWay}"
                Text="{Binding Discount,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>
        

            <!--Unit Availability Picker-->
            <Grid>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <Label 
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Text="{xct:Translate UnitAvailability}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource PickerLabelStyle}"/>
                <Picker 
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding UnitAvailabilityList,Mode=OneWay}" 
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding UnitAvailabilityIndex,Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                        Style="{StaticResource PickerStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding UnitAvailabilityError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding UnitAvailabilityErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />
            
            <!--Electricity Meter-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate ElectricityMeterInfo}"
                Text="{Binding ElecMeter}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding ElecMeterError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding ElecMeterErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />
            
            <!--Water Meter-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate WaterMeterInfo}"
                Text="{Binding WaterMeter}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding WaterMeterError,Mode=OneWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding WaterMeterErrorVis,Mode=OneWay}"
                />
            

            <!--Submit Button-->
            <Button                    
                Text="{xct:Translate Submit}"
                Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
            
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

and my static resourse for styling each view

```
   <!--Entry Style-->
        <Style x:Key="EntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Start"/>
        </Style>

        <!--Button Style-->
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="30"/>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="140"/>
        </Style>
        
        <!--Error Label-->
        <Style x:Key="ErrorLabel" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
        
        <!--Picker Style-->
        <Style x:Key="PickerStyle" TargetType="Picker">
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="300"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </Style>

        <!--Picker Label Style-->
        <Style x:Key="PickerLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Medium"/>
        </Style>
```

Note: the screen shot taken from android device xiaomi redmi note 7

Comment: 1) Does same problem also occur on Android emulator? 2) Is the place on screen where it becomes blank, about the same distance down from top of screen, as the original view before validation? (I'm thinking that maybe the view failed to recalculate its size - but don't want to pursue fixing that if it isn't the problem.) 3) Related to 2, as a test, please comment out most validation code, so that only FIRST ITEM's validation is shown. In that case, do more of the items stay visible?

Answer (score 0):

It might be [this open bug](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14154).

A work-around from [this comment](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14154#issuecomment-828206634):

Replace this:

```
   <ScrollView>
    ...
  </ScrollView>
```

With this:

```
<Grid>
   <ScrollView>
    ...
  </ScrollView>
<Grid>
```

Comment: thank your answer really helped me.